# javascript fetch getting a wrong address

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am trying to make a update part btw I got a wrong address

'abc.com/test/update/test/update/12345' instead of 'abc.com/test/update/1234'

I don't know why I have a duplicate '/test/update/' in url.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
            let form = document.getElementById('form');
            formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("title", form.title.value);
            formData.append("category", form.category.value);
            formData.append("points", form.points.value);

            var full_url = document.URL; 
            var url_array = full_url.split('/') 
            var id = url_array[url_array.length-1];  

            e.preventDefault();

            fetch('test/update/' +id, {
                method: 'PUT',
                body: formData
             })
            .then(response => {
                location.href = '/test/list'
            })
            return false;

        })
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code. In particular, you should print out `full_url`. Most likely it already includes `test/update`.

Comment: `test/update/'` to `/test/update/'`

Answer (score 1):

Change fetch statement to below -

```
fetch('' +id, {
```

Comment: Thank you so much  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 fetch('test/update/' +id,
```

this where the duplication comes from :)
Your id is storing the same thing as the string you are trying to concatenate.